# What is the C# equivalent of VB.Net " IsDBNull"

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB.Net you can write :

```
If Not IsDBNull(oCustomerNameDataRow(0)) Then
    cbCustomerName.Items.Add(oCustomerNameDataRow(0).ToString
End If
```

What is the equivalent of method IsDBNull in C#?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6199433a-a0f6-41e3-a482-d608ef89cf85/what-is-cs-equivalent-for-vbs-isdbnull?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: to the downvoters: this is a viable and good question - either find a reason to flag it (for example it might have been asked before) or stop downvoting things - thank you

Comment: I did not downvote but it this seems to be something that could have easily been looked up on MSDN.

Comment: @RickDavin Seems to be? Have you tried? If so, what did you search for? I can't find anything on MSDN that answers this question as it's asked.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(oCustomerNameDataRow[0]))
{
  //something
}
```

[MSDN (DBNull.Value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yep - from [System.DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

I would say the the equivalent of the [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method *(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information)* located in the [Microsoft.VisualBasic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Information.vb,112) assembley

```vb
Public Function IsDBNull(ByVal Expression As Object) As Boolean
    If Expression Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    ElseIf TypeOf Expression Is System.DBNull Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
Dim result As Boolean = IsDBNull(Nothing)
```

is the [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method *(System.Convert)* located in the [mscorlib](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,184) assembley:

```cs
public static bool IsDBNull(object value) {
    if (value == System.DBNull.Value) return true;
    IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;
    return convertible != null? convertible.GetTypeCode() == TypeCode.DBNull: false;
}
```

```cs
bool result = System.Convert.IsDBNull(null);
```

Comment: **NOT SAME** FOR VB.NET NET 4.5 **IsDBNull**: `If (Expression IsNot Nothing) Then
                flag = If(Not TypeOf Expression Is DBNull, False, True)
            Else
                flag = False
            End If`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create the `Extension Method`. follow this:

```
public static bool IsDBNull(this object val)
{
     return Convert.IsDBNull(val);
}
```

and the use from this `Extension Method`.

```
if(oCustomerNameDataRow[0].IsDBNull())
{
      // ...
}
```

I hope useful.